# How to run multiple structured streams in parallel?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to write to streams parallel, but just the last one is working.

Here is my code.

```
val trump_topic = filteredQueryTrump.select($"ID".as("key"), $"title".as("value"))
   .writeStream.format("kafka")
   .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("10 seconds"))
   .option("kafka.security.protocol", "SASL_SSL")   
   .option("kafka.sasl.mechanism", "SCRAM-SHA-256")   
   .option("kafka.sasl.jaas.config", """org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username="" password="";""")
   .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "rocket-01.srvs.cloudkafka.com:9094")
   .option("topic", "trump")
   .option("checkpointLocation", "/tmp").start()

val biden_topic = filteredQueryBiden.select($"ID".as("key"), $"title".as("value"))
   .writeStream.format("kafka") 
   .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("4 seconds"))
   .option("kafka.security.protocol", "SASL_SSL")   
   .option("kafka.sasl.mechanism", "SCRAM-SHA-256")   
   .option("kafka.sasl.jaas.config", """org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username="" password="";""")
   .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "rocket-01.srvs.cloudkafka.com:9094")
   .option("topic", "biden")
   .option("checkpointLocation", "/tmp").start()
```

I tried `spark.streams.awaitAnyTermination()` but it didn't help either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have **two different checkpoint locations** for each output stream.

Also, do add `awaitAnyTermination` as you already have tried out to ensure the jobs are running continously.

```scala
spark.streams.awaitAnyTermination()
```

---

As an alternative you could combine those two queries into one by doing

```scala
val combinedDf = filteredQueryTrump.select($"ID".as("key"), $"title".as("value"), lit("trump").as("topic"))
  .union(filteredQueryBiden.select($"ID".as("key"), $"title".as("value"), lit("biden").as("topic")))
```

The content of the column `topic` will be interpreted by the spark-sql-kafka-0-10 library to decide into which topic the row should be written to. Theoretically, you can use that technique to write to multiple Kafka topics within one stream. When doing this it is important to *not use* topic option when calling  `writeStream`. However, in that way you will not be able to have two different Trigger durations but only one for the overall stream.

An example you code could look like this:

```scala
val outputQuery = combinedDf.select($"key", $"value", $"topic")
  .writeStream
  .format("kafka") 
  .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("4 seconds"))
  .option("kafka.security.protocol", "SASL_SSL")   
  .option("kafka.sasl.mechanism", "SCRAM-SHA-256")   
  .option("kafka.sasl.jaas.config", """org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username="" password="";""")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "rocket-01.srvs.cloudkafka.com:9094")
  .option("checkpointLocation", "/tmp")

outputQuery.start()
outputQuery.awaitTermination()
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it worked fine when i changed to 2 different checkpoint location :). But i am also a bit curious about the alternative solution. if I do combinedDf, without using the topic option, how can I write to 2 different topics.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I tried this one in my code and it worked as good as the first solution. Appreciate it :)